# CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string DeprtmentName, decimal? TotalSalary>>'

Tags: c#, linq

This is my table's class:

```
public partial class Dept_Emp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string F_Name { get; set; }
    public string L_Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string DeprtmentName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Sal { get; set; }
}
```

Here I want to fetch the sum of `Sal` per `DepartmentName`. I wrote a simple Linq query, but it's throwing the mentioned error at `g.Sum(x => x.Sal)`.

Linq:

```
public IEnumerable<Dept_Emp> GetEmp()
        {
            var xx = (from de in db.Dept_Emp
                     group de by de.DeprtmentName into g
                     select new
                     {
                         DeprtmentName = g.Key,
                         TotalSalary = g.Sum(x => x.Sal)
                     });
            return db.Dept_Emp.GroupBy(d => d.DeprtmentName)
        .Select(grp => new Dept_Emp
        {
            Id = g.First().Id,
            F_Name = g.First().F_Name,
            L_Name = g.First().L_Name,
            Gender = g.First().Gender,
            DeprtmentName = g.Key,
            Sal = g.Sum(x => x.Sal)
        });
        }
```

Comment: This is not the full exception message. What's the "to" type?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, except for the variable name `x` is declared twice! If I change one of them the query works fine.

Comment: @Rene Vogt u can Procede

Comment: You don't get the error in this query. Where do you use `x`? You haven't shown the code which raises the error.

Comment: CS0136 A local or parameter named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or paramete

Comment: @RonaldDusk: yes, you have two variables `x` in the same scope. The query itself and at `g.Sum(x => x.Sal)`. Rename one, i recommend the query name.

Comment: Thank @Tim Schmelter But If I write above Query as IEnumarable<Dept_Emp>  GetData(){  -------Some ---Code ---}Then wat is the Return value

Comment: @RonaldDusk: the return type is `IEnumarable<Dept_Emp>`. You need to create instances of `Dept_Emp` instead of the anonymous type

Comment: coul u plz Help me How to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But If I write above Query as
>
> ```
> IEnumarable<Dept_Emp> GetData(){
>    > -------Some ---Code ---
> }
> ```
>
> Then what is the Return value

Then you need to return `Dept_Emp` instances not anonymous types:

```
return db.Dept_Emp
    .GroupBy(d => d.DeprtmentName)
    .Select(g => new Dept_Emp
     {
         Id = g.First().Id,
         F_Name =  g.First().F_Name,
         L_Name =  g.First().L_Name,
         Gender =  g.First().Gender,
         DeprtmentName =  g.Key,
         Sal  = g.Sum(x => x.Sal)
     });
```

Comment: Could u plz watch my Edited Code  i'm getting Error at g.

Comment: @RonaldDusk: edited my answer, changed `.Select(grp ...` to `.Select(g ...`

Comment: 1+ only for this line (Select(g => new Dept_Emp) showing how to convert anonymous type to specific i didn,t now it before .